# Passing in a file name to Emscripten generated js as an argument

Tags: javascript, html, webassembly, emscripten

A program that I ported over from C to WebAssembly via ecc seems to “work” when run via the emscripten generated html file (it displays the help page as it should when no arguments are passed). However for the program to be used it requires some arguments to be passed in.

Example:
`exampleprogram -option filename`

Essentially I wish to give the user a way to select a file from their desktop and pass that in as an argument to the program and then click another button to run the program. This is to all be run locally as there is some copyright issues with the file that is meant to be selected.
I am still fairly new to html css and js and the most I have done so far is created the basic layout for the page and attached the generated js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run an emscripten-built program with command line arguments you would first set `Module['arguments']` before loading the module's js file.

However getting the file from the user's filesystem into the browser so that emscripten can process it is more complex issue.  For information on how to do that part see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications.

Once you have the file you then need to inject it into he module's virtual filesystem.  For more information on this see: https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html